# Are TF-IDF scores for a single term combined?

Tags: nlp, tf-idf, stop-words

I am reading up about TF-IDF so that I can filter out common words from my corpus. It appears to me that you get a TF-IDF score for each word, document pair.

Which score do you pay attention to? Do you combine the scores across all documents for a word?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TFIDF ex:

```
doc1 = "This is doc1"
doc2 = "This is a different document"
corpus = [doc1, doc2]
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vec = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(corpus)
X.toarray()
return: array([[0.        , 0.70490949, 0.        , 0.50154891, 0.50154891],
   [0.57615236, 0.        , 0.57615236, 0.40993715, 0.40993715]])
vec.get_feature_names()
```

So you have a line/1d array for each doc in the corpus, and that array has len = total vocab in your corpus (can get quite sparse). What score you pay attention to depends on what you're doing, ie finding most important word in a doc you could look for highest TF-idf in that doc. Most important in a corpus, look in the entire array. If you're trying to identify stop words, you could consider finding the set of X number of words with the minimum TF-IDF scores. However, I wouldn't really recommend using TF-IDF to find stop words in the first place, it lowers the weight of stop words, but they still occur frequently which could offset the weight loss. You'd probably be better off finding the most common words and then filtering them out. You'd want to look at either set you generated manually though.

Comment: yeah I'd be using TF-IDF for finding most common words. I'll look into TfidfVectorizer, I was just going to encode the description from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf

Comment: in the example from wiki (which i just added to my post) - which score would you chose in which situation?

Comment: I wouldn't really use TFIDF as I mentioned. I'd recommend just using TF (ie use CountVectorizer from sklearn instead of TfidfVectorizer) and then run sum(X.toarray()) to find the words that occur most frequently overall. Then extract the indexs with the n-highest values, which you then plug into vec.get_feature_names() to find the actual words themselves. If you're really intent on using TFIDF, same process but instead of finding n-max sums, find n-min sums. Note - suming the array should give you a vec.